# drools doesn't recognize ! with custom operators

Tags: drools, mvel

I am getting issue when i use ! along with drools string operations like matches, str[startsWith] . 
Any idea why drools doesn't allow ! with operators like matches , not matches, str[startsWith], str[endsWith], length

The ! works for other operators  like == , < ,> .

### Drl with exception :

```
package example

import com.Customer

rule "sample rule"

no-loop true

dialect "mvel"

when

   $customer:Customer!(state == "CA" && city str[startsWith] "TOP")

then

    System.out.println("Do something" );

end
```

Error Message :
    [ERR 102] Line 11:19 mismatched input '!' in rule "sample rule" in pattern]

### Drl without exception:

```
package example

import com.Customer

rule "sample rule"

no-loop true

dialect "mvel"

when

   $customer:Customer!(state != "CA" && city != "TOP")

then

    System.out.println("Do something" );

end
```

Drools should be able to validate the below drl without any issues,
package example

```
import com.Customer

rule "sample rule"

no-loop true

dialect "mvel"

when

    $customer:Customer!(state == "CA" && city str[startsWith] "TOP")

then

    System.out.println("Do something" );

end
```

Comment: I think "!" operator is not appropriate try "not" instead of "!". You could also consider using a Gudied Template or Guided Decision Table rather than a Guided Rule.

Comment: @Sandesh how did you proceed further for not ?